# How to have a HOVER effect on input[type=button] and how to fix the cursor problem for that?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was building a webpage. I had wanted to add a hover effect of button type input element.

But when I hovered on that input element, I found the cursor was not changing and hover was not working.

```css
#b1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

input[type: "button"]:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<form><input id="b1" type="button" value="LogIn" onclick="window.location.href='http://www.facebook.com/'" /></form>
```

Should I change the `ONCLICK` code?

Comment: `type: "button"` --> `type="button"` (closing as typo)

Comment: I had an on topic question on cursor problem, so it's damn **ON TOPIC**

Comment: read what the banner is saying : *"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error*

Comment: Bro, if you ignore the **Typographical Error** question, i also have another question in the passage about **Cursor**. If the typological error is from of topic, you can ignore that and just answer to the cursor problem, thx :)

Comment: so why did you accept the below answer that is fixing the *typo*? By doing so you confirmed that your question is **only** about the typo.

Comment: Another thing, accepting the typo doesn't really mean i had only the problem of  typo, as you couldn't answer it i though you would have forgotten to read that. I wanted to upvote ur ans bt my reputation is less than 15, so as a return i accepted it; as it solved my problem partly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined your css-selector wrong.

The correct way to address the button is:

```css
input[type=button]:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Read more about CSS Form selectors [here](background-color: green;).